# close vote reviews: are duplicates randomly selected or did people propose them?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

In some close vote reviews (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2751077) there are proposed duplicates.  However, in the close view, there appear to be zero votes for duplicate.  Are duplicates based on actual proposals or are they just selected randomly?

Comment: I think we should randomly select questions.might help us close old bad ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Close votes aren't the only way to get stuff into the queue - us lowly users with less than 3000 rep can flag things to be closed, which doesn't count as a vote but kicks the question into the close-vote queue anyway. (Close flags used to be shown to mods as well, but that was changed not too long ago.) Presumably this question was flagged as a duplicate.